# Attempt to use store on TreePanel fails

Tags: extjs

The following code throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getRootNode' of undefined`. As far as I can understand my store does not register correctly, but I can not figure out why.

Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup() returns `undefined` when I test it in the widget's initComponent(), or anywhere else. Tried forcing storeID, no difference. The rest of the code works, because if I force `root: {}` the widget works correctly.

App.js:

> ```
> Ext.require('Ext.container.Viewport');
>
> Ext.application({
> requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
> name: 'IW',
> appFolder: '/static/js',
> models: ['Page'],
> stores: ['Pages'],
> controllers: ['Pages'],
> views: ['page.PageTree'],
>
> launch: function() {
>     Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
>         layout: 'absolute',
>         items: [
>             {
>                 xtype: 'pagetree', 
>                 title: 'Pages',
>                 x: 20,
>                 y: 20,
>                 width: 300,
>                 height: 300
>             }
>         ]
>     });
> } });
> ```

store/Pages.js:

> ```
> Ext.define('IW.store.Pages', {
> extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
> model: 'IW.model.Page',
> autoLoad: true,
>
> proxy: {
>     type: 'rest',
>     url: '/api/pages',
>     reader: {
>         type: 'json',
>         root: 'pages',
>         successProperty: 'success'
>     }
> },
>
> root: {
>     expanded: true,
>     id: 'frontPage',
>     text: 'Front Page'
> },
>
> constructor: function() {
>     console.log('Constructor of IW.store.Pages');
> }
> ```
>
> });

view/Page/PageTree.js:

> ```
> Ext.define('IW.view.page.PageTree', {
> extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
> alias: 'widget.pagetree',
> width: 640,
> rootVisible: true,
>
> // Does not work
> store: 'Pages',
> // Works
> //root: {},
>
> initComponent: function() {
>     //this.store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(this.store);
>     //console.log(this.store); // Undefined
>     this.callParent();
> } });
> ```

controller/Pages.js:

> ```
> Ext.define('IW.controller.Pages', {
> extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
>
> init: function() {
>     console.log('Init controller');
>     this.control({
>         'pagepagetree': {
>             //
>         }
>     });
> } });
> ```

model/Page.js:

> ```
> Ext.define('IW.model.Page', {
> extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
> fields: ['id', 'wiki', 'path', 'title', 'create_user', 'content', 'readacl', 'writeacl', 'adminacl'] });
> ```

I am probably missing something elementary.. How should I correct this?

Comment: Maybe because you override the constructor, without callParent?

Comment: That's certainly a problem, would suggest you post as an answer. If you're not doing anything, don't override it. If you are, call the parent and make sure to pass the config object.

Comment: @AmitAviv I was going to, just in progress... The problem was in overriding the constructor without callParent. Would you like to post the answer so I can award you points for answering :)

Comment: @user918176 I will, thanks, just thought maybe you had another problem and added the override to test if it's alive at all, and created a new problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the store constructor without calling this.callParent(arguments)